# jQuery find method and specificity with tag name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read how to best tune jQuery [selectors](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/). I just have a doubt on a point for which I have not found a reference on SO.

Given div.my-class and .my-class represent the same thing in the DOM (ie all tags with .my-class are divs) is it generally faster to do:

```
$('#my-id').find('div.my-class')...
```

or

```
$('#my-id').find('.my-class')...
```

A brief explanation about the underlying reason would be great. Is the performance impact significant? The example on jQuery site shows `.find('div.my-class')` but maybe that is just an example.

**EDIT**: having run a [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-method-and-specificity-with-tag-name-al) it seems $('#my-id').find('.my-class') is a bit faster. Probably find('div.my-class') performs a small extra task. The point of this question is to obtain a good practice orientation when dealing with the find method and specificity. I will leave this open for a while to see if someone has the underlying reason for the results we had with jsPerf. Thanks to @dnozay for the additional tests.

Comment: I would imagine that `.find('div.my-class')` would be faster (although not significantly) because you're narrowing down the group of elements to search amongst. That said, running some tests (e.g. jpPerf) would probably be the best way to find out.

Comment: [See for yourself](http://jsperf.com/)

Comment: With modern browsers difference between those 2 is going to be nothing major. Before querySelctorAll was implemented, it was a big deal.

Comment: thanks @Blazemonger but I guess a jsPerf would give me the answer for my computer/browser not what would be the best practice?

Comment: Best *programming* practice is to be no more specific than you need to be. As for performance: It *used* to be that searching for IDs was faster than for tags, which in turn was faster than for classes, because of the underlying vanilla-JS methods that did the work. Today, I'm not sure how the Sizzle engine searches for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't trust anyone without benchmarks to prove it.

http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-method-and-specificity-with-tag-name

With this prep code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="my-id">
    <div class="my-class"></div>
    <div class="foobar"></div>
    <div class="my-class"></div>
    <span class="my-class"></span><!-- should not be matched? -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The first testcase:

```
$('#my-id').find('div.my-class');
```

is 3x slower on my browser than:

```
$('#my-id').find('.my-class');
```

**However** they don't return the same elements.
So it depends on what your html looks like.

## drill-down approach.

This query is trying to check all aspects at once:

```
$('#my-id div.my-class')
```

This query is cutting elements out early by matching an id:

```
$('#my-id').find('div.my-class')
```

This query is going one step further to match the class first, then match the tag.

```
$('#my-id').find('.my-class').filter('div');
```

## more numbers

If you have seen http://jsperf.com/275308711/, then check http://jsperf.com/275308711/2, which adds another testcase.

[image: results on my hardware & browser]

Comment: ok thanks for the jsPerf I was doing one on my own :) Now to the real question why is $('#my-id').find('.my-class') faster?

Comment: the results were skewed because one query matches more elements; let me add more testcases...

Comment: based on my hardware & browser: `$('#my-id').find('.my-class');`

Comment: Yeah, I have the same thing with my [test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-method-and-specificity-with-tag-name-al). I will just use .my-class for the time being

Answer (score 1):

First, get rid of the find.  It's not needed and causes jQuery to execute two selectors instead of one.  Executing one selector is almost always going to be faster as it is executed by the browser and not by jQuery.  Instead write your selector like this:

```
$('#div1 .myclass');
```

As a general rule, when you come to a question like this, the best thing to do is to profile it.  jsperf.com is a useful tool for the job. Your results are likely going to vary by browser.

I've created a basic test which shows the performance to be slightly faster in Chrome with the most specific selector:

http://jsperf.com/275308711

[image]

Comment: jQuery site states it is faster with find

Comment: @Arnaud the tests say otherwise :)  The reason is that it's slower is it's causing jQuery to run the selector twice.  I'd also suggest looking at the jQuery source to see exactly how it's processing the selectors.

Comment: The stats on your benchmarks contradicts your answer.

Comment: I tested on Chrome and FF on my computer and your test says find is faster ... seems this is hardware dependent but anyway the difference is not that big in either cases.

Comment: jQuery uses Sizzle, which checks the selector to see if it can use the `getElementByID`, `getElementsByTagName`, or `getElementsByClassName`. If it can't, then it has to compile a function that will select the elements. That's why [jQuery says using `find` is optimal](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/).